# Configure JD Eclipse with eclipse Kepler [4.3]

Tags: java, java-3d, decompiler

I am currently working on decompiling the `.class` files using `jd eclipse plugin` which is provided at http://jd.benow.ca/ . Although there is no much documentation or steps for installation process. Can someone please guide me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Jar file from this link

[Java Decompiler](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui/releases/download/v1.4.0/jd-gui-1.4.0.jar) 
After that just open the jar file with double click and then do the following process:-
[image][image]

Comment: I have done the above process, I am not clear with the further process. Please can you guide me with that.

Comment: @SoujanyaJ you can find detailed instruction of installing here : 
http://jd.benow.ca/ 
Go to "JD-Eclipse" select "Download Tab" -> Follow "Installation" instructions :
Download and unzip the JD-Eclipse Update Site,
Launch Eclipse,
Click on "Help > Install New Software...",
Click on button "Add..." to add an new repository,
Enter "JD-Eclipse Update Site" and select the local site directory,
Check "Java Decompiler Eclipse Plug-in",
Next, next, next... and restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following URL to install plugins(**Java Decompiler Eclipse Plug-in**) into Eclipse:

http://mchr3k-eclipse.appspot.com/

You can enter this URL in Eclipse by accessing Help -> Install New Software...

Here's I provide graphical stepwise instruction to install it :

[image: Click to enter repository URL]
[image: Add Repository URL]
[image: Click Next and Install]

Comment: I have followed the above process and imported the libraries accordingly. Please tell me how do I run the decompiler over the imported .class files? Also after importing the decompiler libraries I still don't find the JavaDecompiler option in eclipse at Windows>Preferences